# Why Redhat does not include python 3 in centos 7?

Tags: python-3.x, centos7

If python 3 is stable and Centos 7 is a modern version, why not include it in the official repositories as well as python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 7 ships with Python 2 as it is a critical part of the CentOS base system. Python 3 must be installed alongside Python 2 through the CentOS SCL so that default system tools continue to work properly.